# Restrict AWS EC https access

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-ec2

I’ve just Upload my Api backend to an EC2 server.
My mobile app is développed un react native and my api backend in php.
My backend is joinable with a https request by any ip un the world.
I want to restrict access, but I dont know how.
I just can restrict by ip adress but my react native app is installed in multiple mobiles phones
Si how can I restrict access ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Restrict access in what way? Can you please explain?

Comment: Restrict api access to only mobile app

Comment: You want to restrict your API to only accept requests from the app? You'd need to use some sort of asymmetric / public / private keys like a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I think of utilization AWS Application Loadbalancer's capability of redirect traffic based on HTTP/HTTPS header values. So you can identify where the request coming from by analyzing `User-Agent` key of the header and based on that redirect traffic.

You can find more on how to create rules for your Application Loadbalancer from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html).